# Python requests.post does not force Elasticsearch to create missing index

Tags: python, python-3.x, elasticsearch, python-requests

I want to push data to my Elasticsearch server using :

```
requests.post('http://localhost:9200/_bulk', data=data_1 + data_2)
```

and it complains that the index does not exist. I try creating the index manually:

```
    curl -X PUT http://localhost:9200/_bulk
```

and it complains that I am not feeding a body to it:

```
    {"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"parse_exception","reason":"request body is required"}],"type":"parse_exception","reason":"request body is required"},"status":400}
```

Seems like a bit of a chicken and egg problem here. How can I create that `_bulk` index, and then post my data?

EDIT:

My data is very large to even understand the schema. Here is a small snippet:

```
'{"create":{"_index":"products-guys","_type":"t","_id":"0"}}\n{"url":"http://www.plaisio.gr/thleoraseis/tv/tileoraseis/LG-TV-43-43LH630V.htm","title":"TV LG 43\\" 43LH630V LED Full HD Smart","description":"\\u039a\\u03b1\\u03b9 \\u03cc\\u03bc\\u03bf\\u03c1\\u03c6\\u03b7 \\u03ba\\u03b1\\u03b9 \\u03ad\\u03be\\u03c5\\u03c0\\u03bd\\u03b7, \\u03bc\\u03b5 \\u03b9\\u03c3\\u03c7\\u03c5\\u03c1\\u03cc \\u03b5\\u03c0\\u03b5\\u03be\\u03b5\\u03c1\\u03b3\\u03b1\\u03c3\\u03c4\\u03ae \\u03b5\\u03b9\\u03ba\\u03cc\\u03bd\\u03b1\\u03c2 \\u03ba\\u03b1\\u03b9 \\u03bb\\u03b5\\u03b9\\u03c4\\u03bf\\u03c5\\u03c1\\u03b3\\u03b9\\u03ba\\u03cc webOS 3.0 \\u03b5\\u03af\\u03bd\\u03b1\\u03b9 \\u03b7 \\u03c4\\u03b7\\u03bb\\u03b5\\u03cc\\u03c1\\u03b1\\u03c3\\u03b7 \\u03c0\\u03bf\\u03c5 \\u03c0\\u03ac\\u03b5\\u03b9 \\u03c3\\u03c4\\u03bf \\u03c3\\u03b1\\u03bb\\u03cc\\u03bd\\u03b9 \\u03c3\\u03bf\\u03c5","priceCurrency":"EUR","price":369.0}\n{"create":{"_index":"products-guys","_type":"t","_id":"1"}}\n{"url":"http://www.plaisio.gr/thleoraseis/tv/tileoraseis/Samsung-TV-43-UE43M5502.htm","title":"TV Samsung 43\\" UE43M5502 LED ...
```

This is essentially someone else's code, that I need to make work. It seems that the "data" object I am passing to the PUT method is a string.

When I use `requests.post('http://localhost:9200/_bulk', data=data)`

I get `<Response [406]>`,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do a bulk request using `requests`

```
response = requests.post('http://localhost:9200/_bulk', data= data=data_1 + data_2, headers={'content-type':'application/json', 'charset':'UTF-8'})
```

**Old Answer**

I recommend using the [bulk helper](https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/v7.11.0/helpers.html#bulk-helpers) from the python library

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch, helpers

client = Elasticsearch("localhost:9200")

def gendata():
    mywords = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz']
    for word in mywords:
        yield {
            "_index": "mywords",
            "word": word,
        }

resp = helpers.bulk(
client,
gendata(),
index = "some_index",
)
```

If you didn't touch the elasticsearch configuration a new index will be created on document indexing.

About the ways you tried:

1. Probably the query is malformed. To do bulk ingest the body shape is different than just sending the docs as a json array.
2. You are doing PUT instead of post and you have to specify the documents you want to ingest.

There is no need to create the empty index first. Just in case you want to do you can just do :

`curl -X PUT http://localhost:9200/index_name`

Comment: Not sure how the above helps. All I want is to replace the line 

requests.post('http://localhost:9200/_bulk', data=data_1 + data_2)

I already have the data.

Comment: Can I see what data are you pushing? if you are not specifying the index name in the body then you have http://localhost:9200/index_name/_bulk

Your body should look like

{ "index" : { "_index" : "test", "_id" : "1" } }
{ "field1" : "value1" }

Comment: unfortunately I cannot share the data. Basically all I want is just to create that _bulk index and add the data in json format to it.

Comment: But what's the shape of the data? if is an array of json it will not work without the helper I showed you. If you want to use POST directly you have to parse into the right format https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-bulk.html

Comment: try adding this Content-Type to your request application/json; charset=utf-8

Comment: response = requests.post('http://localhost:9200/_bulk', data= data=data_1 + data_2, headers={'content-type':'application/json', 'charset':'UTF-8'})

Comment: InvalidSchema: No connection adapters were found for 'localhost:9200/_bulk'

Comment: add the http:// to localhost, SO convert it into a hyperlink

Comment: Now it returns : <Response [200]> Any idea what that is ?  If I look in the brower, I get : "Incorrect HTTP method for uri [/_bulk] and method [GET], allowed: [POST, PUT]"

Comment: Code 200 means OK , check your index. If you put a url in the browser will do a GET request and bulk is POST . Please confirm if it worked to edit the answer

Comment: check if the index has docs curl -X GET http://localhost:9200/products-guys/_search